# mono Run Time Exception on Catalina MacOS

Tags: mono, dylib, macos-catalina

I have an application that is made by `.NET` and i use `mono 6.4.0.198` (i use the newest mono so the app is compatible with **Catalina MacOS**) to run it on the Mac machine, on my machine the mono is installed so the app works fine, but when i run the app on other Macs it return the following exception

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Diagnostics.SystemDiagnosticsSection' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Diagnostics.AssertSection' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: /libmono-native-compat.dylib assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+Sys.GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes(byte*,int)
  at Interop.GetRandomBytes (System.Byte* buffer, System.Int32 length) [0x00000] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.Guid.NewGuid () [0x00000] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor..cctor () [0x00034] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty..ctor (System.String name, System.Type type, System.Object defaultValue, System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyOptions options) [0x00000] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.AssertSection..cctor () [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init(intptr)
  at System.Diagnostics.SystemDiagnosticsSection..cctor () [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x0001a] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00095] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache) [0x00009] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Boolean wrapExceptions, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x00027] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00020] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <b814b509d4ad406fb40c6c93e38929e7>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00026] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.SectionInfo.CreateInstance () [0x00000] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionInstance (System.Configuration.SectionInfo config, System.Boolean createDefaultInstance) [0x0001c] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x0002c] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00016] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00006] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00005] in <181a8ffed1274b05b3ed7ea8bc6e1333>:0 
  at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection () [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize () [0x0002a] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize () [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings () [0x0004e] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners () [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Trace.get_Listeners () [0x00000] in <6aa0b19d109a447c94d1b43ec4471dc6>:0 
  at Zoolz.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00040] in <d6a87962027b42c6878475ce75623731>:0
```

clearly its a missing dll `libmono-native-compat.dylib` i added this dll at the application resources alongside other dlls but the app still returning the same missing dll exception, how i can direct mono to dll so i would fix this problem

Comment: Any luck with this so far?  I've tried different versions of mono (6.0.0 through the current available 6.8.0), but they all end up in the same DLLNotFoundException on libmono-native-compat.dylib. Copying the dylib to the end location of my executable doesn't work either, and mkbundle it into the executable doesn't work because of some bad image format exception.

Comment: i have answered this question, check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by

creating a file called `fix.config` and it contains the following XML

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="System.Native" target="libmono-native-compat.dylib" os="!windows" />
    <dllmap dll="System.Net.Security.Native" target="libmono-native-compat.dylib" os="!windows" />
    <dllmap dll="System.Security.Cryptography.Native.Apple" target="libmono-native-compat.dylib" os="osx" />
</configuration>
```

the i copied the three dylibs that are mentioned in the XML to the path `Application/MyApp.app/Contents/lib`

then in the in the building script i added to the tool `mkbundle` the following command

`--config $SETUP_DIR/fix.config` and setup path is the path where im creating my `.pkg` file

NOTE: im using mono version `6.4.0.198`

Comment: Where you found libmono-native-compat.dylib ?
I have Big Sur 11.4 and I cannot locate this file

Comment: As far as i remember i installed mono framework and then copied it from the dylibs that comes with the mono framework, i forgot the exact path

Answer (score 0):

I had many errors when I installed the macOS Catalina until I decide to give permission to my /private/tmp folder. It seems all apps work now. I don't know if it's your case but just in case try this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /private/tmp
```

Comment: no actually my case is a missing dylib, thanks anyway